# [Android]How to load swf file in Android (API 23)

Tags: java, android, flash, android-webview

I want to load swf file in Android , but it seems that Android don't support swf.
I google it,and most of developers suggest to use webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.loadurl("....swf");
```

but setPluginsEnabled was removed and setPluginState is deprecated in Api  level 23.

Comment: "but it seems that Android don't support swf" -- correct. Adobe dropped support for Flash on Android years ago. Virtually no devices running Android 4.1+ will have it, and that means that <8% of Play Store devices will have it, based on the November 2015 edition of [the dashboards](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: deprecated means it can be used.

Comment: @tinysunlight It didn't work...

Comment: @CommonsWare  But there is a video api only provides swf format

Comment: SWF is not a video. FLV is a video. And even that is as far as I can see not listed here: [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Anything non standard needs your own codec.

Comment: Then talk to the provider of the "video api" and ask them what they recommend for integrating with their "video api" on Android.

Comment: @zapl   this is the video link api provided: http://dispatcher.video.qiyi.com/disp/shareplayer.swf?vid=feadedd3bf47f8644d818eb25aecef62&tvId=420132400&coop=&cid=&bd=1

Comment: @CommonsWare  this is the video link api provided: http://dispatcher.video.qiyi.com/disp/shareplayer.swf?vid=feadedd3bf47f8644d818eb25aecef62&tvId=420132400&coop=&cid=&bd=1

Comment: That's not a proper video api for Android. That's a link to a flash player with a video id as parameter that you can embedd into websites. A proper api for Android needs to expose the video directly as MP4 or so. If they don't provide that, maybe they don't want to you include the videos into your app?

Comment: @zapl oh,I got it .Thanks for your time,zapl .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "but it seems that Android don't support swf"

Yes and as you've been told... Adobe stopped allowing Flash Player on mobile browsers. They instead recommend that you open FlashPlayer content within an app only because.. drumroll... Adobe have [their own tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_AIR) to create Android apps and only their tool allows opening SWF within a mobile app.

The catch is that any SWF loaded into an app cant just run its own code (could be un-safe code from a bad-minded person). So the next best things is to use Flash's own StageWebView to open a html page that has a flash embed and everything runs perfectly like on a computer browser (only this time via that StageWebView part of your Flash-made Android app).

So to answer..

> I want to load swf file in Android

simply download the latest **[Flash CC](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/flash.html)** (dev toolkit) and re-create your app through ActionScript-3 code instead of Java code. They are both C-like languages (though I feel AS3 is closer to C# than Java in terms of API names etc but as you can see where Java/Android has "**[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)**" well AS3 has "**[StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)**" so it might not be that hard to switch for this app (if important enough to justify learning a new OOP language)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView

Useful for playing `swf` files.

Also you need to set `plugin.state.flash = true;` in GeckoView..

The bad idea is your `apk` will increase 20-25 mb if you choose to use GeckoView (if i did not remember wrong) , because `GeckoView` works with jni...